# Clean language: append number in end of file, fwritei doesn't work

Tags: functional-programming, clean-language

I'm trying to write function that receive `[String]` which are names of files, `String` which is the name of the files directory and `*f`. The function will append to each file an integer in the end.

Here is what I got so far:

```
import StdEnv
import StdFile
import FileManipulation

appendNumInEndOfVmFiles :: [String] String *f -> String
appendNumInEndOfVmFiles [] dirname w = "finished"
appendNumInEndOfVmFiles [x:xs] dirname w
# path = dirname +++ "\\\\" +++ x
# (ok,file,files) = fopen path FAppendText w
# file = fwritei 12 file 
# (ok2,_) = fclose file w
= appendNumInEndOfVmFiles xs dirname w


Start w
// 1. Receive name of directory from the user.
# (io,w) = stdio w                                  // open stdio
# io = fwrites "Enter name of directory:\n" io      // ask for name
# (name,io) = freadline io                          // read in name
# name = name % (0, size name - 2)                  // remove \n from name
# (ok,w) = fclose io w                              // close stdio
| not ok = abort "Couldn't close stdio"             // abort in case of         failure

// 2. Get a list of all file names in that directory.
# (dir,w) = getDirectoryContents (RelativePath [PathDown name]) w
# fileList = getNamesOfFilesInDirectory (getEntriesList dir)

= appendNumInEndOfVmFiles (getVmFiles fileList) name w
```

Assume that `getVmFiles` is defined in my `FileManipulation.dcl` file and in the context of this problem `name` is `"myDir"` and file list is `["hello.vm","Wiki.vm"]`

For some reason, even that I got "finished" message on the screen, the files aren't modified. No matter what kind of integer I give to `fopen`, even if its `FWriteText` or `FWriteData` its still doing nothing... also even if I'm using `fwritec` or `fwrites` with characters nothing happened.

What I'm missing here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason, even that I got "finished" message on the screen, the files aren't modified.

This is due to [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). In `appendNumInEndOfVmFiles`, the result of `fclose` is not used, so `fclose` is not evaluated. Because of this, `fwritei` does not need to be evaluated either. You can fix this by adding a guard on `ok2`:

```
# (ok2,_) = fclose file w
| not ok2 = abort "fclose failed\n"
= appendNumInEndOfVmFiles xs dirname w
```

However, the typical way to do this would be to rewrite the function to return a `*f` instead of a `String`, so that this unique value is not lost. As long as the result is used, then, the `fwritei` is evaluated. You can potentially make the `*f` argument strict (i.e. add a `!` in front). This would make sure that it is evaluated before entering the function, so that all lingering file closes have been performed.

---

There are some more issues with your code:

1. Here, `w` is used twice, which is illegal because it is of a strict type. You should use `(ok2,w)` in the guard to continue with the same environment.

   ```
   # (ok2,_) = fclose file w
   = appendNumInEndOfVmFiles xs dirname w
   ```
2. The `appendNumInEndOfVmFiles` needs to have a type context `| FileSystem f` to resolve overloading of `fopen` and `fclose`.

---

Lastly:

> ... even if its `FWriteText` or `FWriteData` ...

Just so you know: the difference would be that the first would write the integer in an ASCII representation whereas the second would write it binary as 4 or 8 bytes (depending on the bitwidth of your system).

Comment: Thanks. I fixed my code and its working. can you explain more about this `| FileSystem f` what actually happen there? also why I must use `(ok2,w)` in the guard? I thought `_` is good enough.

Comment: @ZENir sorry, your comment got lost in my inbox. `| FileSystem f` is a class context, you can read more about it in [section 6](https://cloogle.org/doc/#CleanRep.2.2_8.htm;jump=_Toc311798055) of the language report. In short, it contains the necessary functions `fopen` and `fclose`, which can have different implementations depending on `f`. The guard is to force evaluation of `fclose`. It is somewhat similar to what happens in a C-like language when you write `(true || f(x))`: `f(x)` is not executed because it is not needed to evaluate `||`. Are you familiar with lazy evaluation?